# Can't mount CIFS share but can navigate it

Tags: centos, mount, network-shares, samba, windows-2000

I have been given access to a network share on a Windows 2000 server, which I need to access from a CentOs 7 machine.

I have created the credentials file:

```
username=MYUSER
password=MYPASS
domain=DOMAIN
```

and I can list the share correctly:

```
[root@localhost ~]# smbclient -L //share.domain.com -E -A /root/.credentials
Domain=[DOMAIN_NT_DOM1] OS=[Windows 5.0] Server=[Windows 2000 LAN Manager]
...
```

Even though sometimes I get an intermittent error saying:

```
Connection to share.domain.com failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_DEVICE_ERROR)
NetBIOS over TCP disabled -- no workgroup available
```

I can even copy the files locally with the `-Tc` switch.

However, when trying to mount the share, I get a "permission denied" error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount.cifs //share.domain.com/folder/folder2 /root/shared -o 'credentials=/root/.credentials,sec=ntlmv2' -v
domain=domain.com
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=172.16.70.4,unc=\\share.domain.com\folder,sec=ntlmv2,user=MYSUER,,domain=domain.com,prefixpath=folder2,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Why can I list and tar files with `smbclient` but cannot mount the share?

Comment: Are you sure that your server uses "ntlmv2" as the authentication protocol?

Comment: Actually, no, but I have tried them all, the result is always the same.

Comment: Just to be sure you tried all possible parameters of "sec" as listed in your local manual accessible through `man mount.cifs`?You could also try to set the option "vers" to "1.0", "2.0", "2.1", "3.0", maybe you're using the wrong protocol version.

Comment: Yes, tried all possible combinations of `sec` and `vers`, error message went from `Permission denied` to `Operation not supported` or `Unknown error 524`, still no good.

Comment: Why do your errors show that `domain=domain.com`?Shouldn't it be `domain=BERCO_NT_DOM1` as shown by `smbclient`(`Domain=[BERCO_NT_DOM1] OS=[Windows 5.0] Server=[Windows 2000 LAN Manager]`)?

Comment: I was told the domain is registered as `domain.com` however it has a different NETBIOS (?) name, I tried to use that too, same error.

Comment: Try `mount.cifs //share.domain.com/folder/folder2 /root/shared -o username=yourusername,sec=yourauthprotocol`, does it work?Also try `yourdomain\\yourusername` as your username.

Comment: You found it! I do not know why, but removing the domain from the credentials file allowed me to mount the share! It seems that, in this setup, the domain is required by `smbclient` (it won't connect without) but not for `mount.cifs`.

Comment: Glad that it works.

Comment: Does it also work with the credentials file?

Comment: If I remove the domain, yes it does. If you'll make it an answer I'd gladly upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by removing the `domain` option from the `mount.cifs` command or rather by removing it from the credentials file.

### Example:

In the credentials file before modification:

```
username=MYUSER  
password=MYPASS  
domain=DOMAIN
```

In the credentials file after modification:

```
username=MYUSER  
password=MYPASS
```

---

Before command modification:

```
mount.cifs //share.domain.com/folder/folder2 /root/shared -o username=yourusername,sec=yourauthprotocol,domain=yourdomain
```

After command modification:

```
mount.cifs //share.domain.com/folder/folder2 /root/shared -o username=yourusername,sec=yourauthprotocol
```